# How to display attribute swatch image in listing page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, swatches

I am using Magento 2.2.2

I have created one attribute "Manufacturer". Input type of this attribute is visual swatch. I have added values with swatch images in this attribute.

I have selected different values of this attribute in different products. Now I am trying to display this images in listing page. See below code:

```
 <?php $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection(); ?>
     <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
          <?php $m = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                        $swatchCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Swatches\Model\ResourceModel\Swatch\Collection');
                        $swatchHelper= $objectManager->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media"); 
                        $item = $swatchCollection->getFirstItem();
                        $SwatchImage = $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_image', $_product->getValue());
                        $thumbImage =  $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_thumb', $_product->getValue());
                  ?>
                    <?php /*?><div class="brand"> <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/product_brand_logo.jpg'); ?>" alt="" /> </div><?php */?>
                    <div class="brand"> <img src="<?php echo $thumbImage; ?>" alt="" /></div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have added this code in `list.phtml` file but I am not getting swatch image for corresponding product in listing page. So how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer to your question, and I'm going to share it because maybe it helps somebody in the future:

1.- Enter to admin panel

2.- `Stores` (left menu)

3.- `Product` (under attribute section)

4.- Select the attribute you want to edit, for example `Manufacturer`

5.- `Storefront Properties` (in the Attribute Information menu on the left)

6.- Look for `Used in product listing` option and set it to `YES`

And then Incase anyone is experiencing the same problem, the problem was the catalog.xml file - items were missing from this.

Comment: I have already tried this solution but still I can't see image in front end. So I think the issue is in the programming.

Comment: then you can compare default `catalog_category_view.xml` and theme `catalog_category_view.xml`